# Why are some entries highligted in my .bib file in gedit?

Tags: bibtex, editors, gedit

I'm using the latex plugin for gedit in ubuntu 16.04.  Some entries are hilighted.  It becomes unreadable when using some of the darker color schemes.  Does the hilighting indicate something wrong with the entry?  All entries are copy/pasted from google scholar.

[image]

Comment: Maybe the plugin doesn't know the `@misc` entry type. Try changing the `@misc` to `@article` to see if the highlighting goes away.  Anyways, I think this question is off-topic here. Maybe it should belong in AskUbuntu or StackOverflow.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik that's just an example.  Plenty of `@article`s have the same highlighting.  You might be right about moving.

Comment: Well, then I don't know. The entry seems to be correct, looking form here. To make sure, copy the contents from a non-highlighted entry to a highlighted one and see if it changes something. If it doesn't, then my next guess will be a bug in the plugin :/

Comment: Maybe it's picking up on the colons? Could you try trimming the values and see if it's picking up on a specific word? The "Chapter" is also formatted as a key even though it's part of the title.